# What's the purpose of the 'ValueType' property on IBsonSerializer, MongoDB C# driver 2.2.2

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, bson

I'm implementing a custom serializer by implementing the interface: IBsonSerializer defined on MongoDB C# Driver version 2.2.2.

The methods Serialize and Deserialize are clear, but there's a property:

`Type ValueType { get; }`

The [documentation page on mongodb.org for IBsonSerializer](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0/html/T_MongoDB_Bson_Serialization_IBsonSerializer.htm) only says:
"Gets the type of the value."
The thorough API reference on [mongodb.github.io](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/bson/serialization/) has no reference to this property at all.

What's the purpose of this getter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's so that the driver knows what type this serializer applies to. When using the generic interface, IBsonSerializer, then the ValueType property will return typeof(T). However, the driver uses the non-generic IBsonSerializer a lot and needs to know this information, so there is a property to provide it.

Perhaps some context for why you are asking would help me provide a more specific answer.